# Unable to create loginKey via Rally Encoder page

Tags: rally

I need to display Rally charts on Confluence. All the research I have done tells me about loginKey feature of Rally. I am supposed to generate the loginKey via the [Encoder page](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/html/EncoderPage.html). I have solely followed the instructions provided on [this](https://rallycommunity.rallydev.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_ARTICLE_SEARCH_RESULT&id=kA014000000oeOk) page, but couldn't make the submit button work.

I am using a read-only user created on the free Rally Community Edition.

I am unable to understand what is being missed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a recent CA Agile Central security update that disabled JSONP by default. Both the LoginKey encoding page and any apps that use LoginKey will require JSONP to be enabled. A CA Agile Central Administrator can re-enable JSONP in the Subscription Settings as follows:

[image: JSONPSubscriptionSetting]

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I got it solved after Rally support team asked me if I had JSON enabled in subscription. Once I enabled it using the administrator user, the submit button got enabled and I was able to generate the loginKey.